# Why is the flag link hidden on review pages?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags

The links `share | edit | close | flag` are hidden when viewing the post from a review queue. I know we don't need `share`, and `edit` is already a button above. But there are cases where we should flag, (e.g., flagging for spam or migration) instead of, or in addition, to casting a close vote. The `flag` link should either be shown below the question under review, and/or as a button next to 'Edit.'